# Twilio conversation fetch all users

Tags: twilio, chat, twilio-conversations

I am using twilio conversations sdk for chat integration in my application. However when I try to start a new chat, i want to fetch all the existing users in my twilio chat service. I read about getSubscribedUsers() in twilio but that is not working for me. Can someone help me?

I want to know how to fetch all users list